# Getting variable from php file called by ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have main file `index.php`. Where user perform login I load `url.php` in `<div>` inside `index.php` through ajax request.

Now on url.php, on button click event I submit the form and post data to `data.php` file. As `url.php` is loaded into index.php, button click event on url.php will call function in  section of index.php.
I am getting two variable `$x` and `$y` as a result on data.php.

On index.php I have JS function where I want to use `$x` and `$y`. How can I retrieve?

index.php

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //------------------script 2 starts ---------
    function showUser(form, e) {
      //alert(myid);
      e.preventDefault();
      e.returnValue=false;
      var xmlhttp;
      var sent = form.elements['sent'].value;
      //var sent2 = form.elements['sent2'].value;
      //alert(sent2);
      //var divElements = document.getElementById('d1').innerHTML;
      var text1 = document.getElementById('previewUrl').innerText || document.getElementById('previewUrl').textContent;
      var text2 = document.getElementById('previewTitle').innerText || document.getElementById('previewTitle').textContent;
      var text3 = document.getElementById('previewDescription').innerText || document.getElementById('previewDescription').textContent;
      //alert(text3);      
      console.log(sent);

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
        xmlhttp.open(form.method, form.action, true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


      sent = encodeURIComponent(sent);
      text1 = encodeURIComponent(text1);
      text2 = encodeURIComponent(text2);
      text3 = encodeURIComponent(text3);

      xmlhttp.send('sent=' + sent + '&text1=' + text1 + '&text2=' + text2 + '&text3=' + text3);
    }

  </script>
```

+

```
$.ajax({
                         url:'url.php'
                         ,async:     true
                         ,type : 'POST'
                         ,cache:     false
                         ,data : 'myid=' + myid
                         ,dataType:  'html'
                         ,success:   function(data){
                           $('body').html(data);
                           FB.XFBML.parse();
                         }
                       }
                             );
```

url.php

```
<form action="data.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
```

data.php

```
 if (preg_match_all('/[^=]*=([^;@]*)/', shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Desktop/test/b '$test'"),  $matches)){ //Values stored in ma. 
    echo "hi";    
    $x = (int) $matches[1][0]; //optionally cast to int
    $y = (int) $matches[1][1];
```

this `x` and `y` I want to fetch in index.php.

I know this is not impossible. But complex to thing for me!

Comment: when you say you load url.php, is it a ajax load or a frame inside the index.php?  The page navigation is not very clear in the question. could you explain it very crisp as to how the events occur. 
something like this index.php -> ajax -> url.php (same window using iframe) -> form submit and so on

Comment: @nandu: I load it in <div> insdie index.php. Edited question

Comment: when you submit the page it would automatically move to the submitted page. you cannot have the values in the former page because it doesn't stay there.  Its a different case if you are using frames or iframes though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred method of sending data back from the server side is responding with JSON response..

```
$data['x'] = $x;
$data['y'] = $y;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

That should give a response to your ajax callback, so you could use it like this:

```
$.post('data.php', { "myid": id }, function(data) {
    console.log(data.x); //data.x = $x
    console.log(data.y); //data.y = $y
});
```

I didn't test the code to see if it actually works, but it should give an idea of what to do. Let me know if it makes sense :)

Comment: good to know this. If I declare one global var in `index.php`. Then I assign above `data.x` to that variable inside function where I fetch it. After that can I use it globaly in any other function?

Comment: thanks bro. But please see. I `data.php` is as a action in form submit. `Showuser()` is the function where I post the value to `data.php`. How can I get `data.x` and `data.y` in `showuser()` function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve only two value.
Simplest solution just like boiling a egg is:

just print both value in with separating value like ':'

```
echo $x.':'.$y;
```

and when you getting response. separate value with ':' and then you can use them..

or JSON response is also good practice for this.

Comment: Thanks but on that page alredy some othe echos! probably json will do

Comment: ya json is coolest way to do it. it also good for number of response attribute.